# Using Silverlight With MVC To Create An Online POS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to create an online POS that interfaces with someone's card reader on their computer. After some research I found that the best way to be able to interact with someones hardware through my MVC app is to use a Silverlight project in my MVC solution.

However, I need help as I am not really sure where to start with this as I have researched using Silverlight with MVC and trying to use hardware through Silverlight in my MVC app and I have gotten nowhere.

Can anyone help me out with some starting points to find out how to first get the silverlight app to recognize the card reader and then to integrate that into my existing mvc app?

Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, I have no Silverlight experience. However, considering (a) Microsoft stopped Silverlight development (last version is 5, released in 2011), (b) support will end in late 2021 (but end of 2016 for non-IE browsers), and (c) it already doesn't work in Chrome anymore, I would caution against starting new development with Silverlight. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?C2=12905 and https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL5.html

Comment: We recently did something similar, most card reader vendors have their own .NET Library for interacting with their devices. We created a Web API service that accepted certain arguments (cash amount, transaction type .. etc) from the clients web browser, the API then interacted with the vendors library which would communicate with the hardware and return to us the relevant response.

Comment: @Speedbird186 I just heard that from a colleague yesterday. I was a little disappointed.

Comment: @uk2k05 That was my fallback idea was to create my own windows service or maybe a windows forms app. I don't want to restrict myself to only being able to use one kind of card reader, do you know of any way to support multiple devices through some kind of library?